# No space left on device ubuntu AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, ubuntu, anaconda

After setting up Anaconda on Ubuntu through AWS, I configured Jupiter notebook and installed all PySpark and then tried to import it to the script however it returned

```
TypeError: namedtuple() missing 3 required keyword-only arguments: 'verbose', 'rename', and 'module'
```

The reason is Spark 2.1.0 doesn't support python 3.6.0. the solution is changing the python version in anaconda environment.
I then applied this command:

> - [x] conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
> - [x] activate py35

However, applying this command will download files and then an error will occur saying:

```
[Errno 28] No space left on device
```

When checking `df -i` it shows that the 3 pop nodes are 100% which means they are full
I can not delete files and If I could what are the files that should be deleted to make space

Keeping in mind this is all done on AWS using the standard free trial package

Comment: maybe you want to check if the disks are properly mounted. We have observed that when using python 3.5, the disk will dismount by itself after a heavy spark operations. Upgrading to 3.7 was the solution for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that python 3.5 is needed what you should to do is remove python 3.6 and install python 3.5 instead of working around with configuration changing. Also, please double check what is the need of your application, in case disk amount is used up, you should consider adding new space.